# Not able to store twitter data in flume

Tags: hdfs, flume

We we successful in extracting the data from twitter but we couldn't save it on our system using flume.Can you please explain

Comment: Please share more details about your setup?

Answer (score -1):

```
you might have problem in channel or sink may be that's why u r data is not storing in hdfs.

try to understan  this one

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://yourIP:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%M/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

and chek with jps if your data node and namenode is working
```